# How to move layer with click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I'm making a menu that slides in from the right side of the screen when the menu icon is clicked. Thing is, I don't know how to create the jquery for it. Right now I was able to make the menu slide to cover half the screen after pageload, but can someone help me change it to animate after menu icon is clicked and then slide back to the right(left:100%) when menu icon is clicked a second time?

I can get it to work on pageload but not with:

```
$("button").click(function(){
```

Here is what I have that works:

**CSS**

```
#menulayer {
height: 100%;
width: 100vw;
background-color: #999;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
left: 100%;
}
```

**JQ**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#menulayer").delay(3000).animate({left:'50%'});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I used jQuery's `on` for the click binding, rather than `click` due to improved memory usage and for handling dynamic elements added after initial load. To show and hide the menu, a simple `toggleClass` does the trick. You can see in the CSS we set the menu's initial state offscreen, and then, once the `open` class is added, we smoothly animate it onscreen.

**Note:** when moving DOM elements around, you want to use `translate` rather than `left`, `right`, etc. Animations are smoother this way and you'll avoid the glitchy behavior (or "jank") sometimes involved with non-optimized animations. [1]

```js
$('.toggle-button').on('click', function() {
  $('.menu').toggleClass('open')
})
```

```css
.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.menu {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: 0.5s transform;
}

.menu.open {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle-button">toggle menu</button>

<ul class="menu">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

[1] [High Performance Animations](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)

Comment: Awesome, this seems to be working perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Great! If you're satisfied, please mark my answer as the solution.